# Failing to login to WBPlay from iOS device

Tags: mortal-kombat-x-mobile

I have account on WBPlay, which works when logging in from Android (all data that is in cloud copies to my local device).

But when I log in to it from iOS it tells me that "There is no corresponding account in WBID with this email".

What am I doing wrong?